# polygot persistence gremlin queries help needed

Tags: eclipse, oracle, neo4j, gremlin

I tried to export tables from `oracle` to to `neo4j` using `gremlin polygot` queries. But not succeeded. I am using `TinkerGraph` for this.

The below code is working fine in eclipse ide. But not able to run in gremlin-groovy-2.4.0 REPL.

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
import groovy.sql.*

OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource()
ds.user = 'scott'
ds.password = 'tiger'
ds.driverType = 'thin'
ds.serverName = 'localhost'
ds.portNumber = 1521
ds.databaseName = 'test' 

Sql sql = new Sql(ds)

sql.eachRow('select * from survey4') { row -> println row.name }

sql.close()
```

Comment: I see you responded to yourself below....is this working for you now?

Comment: Actually only got success in connection to oracle.But node and vertex creation still pending.

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this one line solution in gremlin-groovy REPL:

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
import groovy.sql.*
OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();ds.user = 'scott';ds.password = 'tiger';ds.driverType = 'thin';ds.serverName = 'localhost';ds.portNumber = 1521;ds.databaseName = 'test';Sql sql = new Sql(ds);sql.eachRow('select * from survey4') { row -> println row.name };sql.close()
```